# how to validate the pdf viewer in browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a button as 'PDF View' and once i click, it opens a another new browser window as a pdf viewer and i navigated to second window. Here i am trying to validate whether some pdf content is displayed on that page. I do not need to validate any pdf text but just need to validate some content is available. 
Here i try to validate the div tag (with id) is present and displayed on the browser window and for some reason it is not identifying that element. Please help me with whats wrong with my code. Any other suggestion or solution to validate would be helpful here.

```
Title of the browser is : Application V5 - PDF Viewer
URL of the browser is : https://sample.com/preferences/pdfviewer.jsp
```

the respective html code is

```
<div id="content">
    <embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="https://sample.com/servlet/pdfviewer" stream-url="chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/23576f4e-363a-4f60-a63a-b770beb66c41" headers="Cache-Control: private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=image.pdf
Content-Length: 23721
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2020 18:53:13 GMT
Expires: Thu, 09 Jan 2020 18:53:18 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Server: Apache
" background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="56" javascript="allow" top-level-url="undefined">
</div>
```

My script has

```
WebElement pdfViewButton = browser.findElement(By.id("frmResults:btnPdfView"));
pdfViewButton.click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

Set<String> AllWindowHandles = browser.getWindowHandles();
String window1 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[0];
scenario.write("Currently in Parent Window = " + AllWindowHandles.toArray()[0]);
scenario.write(browser.getCurrentUrl());
scenario.write(browser.getTitle());
scenario.write(String.valueOf(AllWindowHandles.size()));

String window2 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1];
scenario.write("Switching to Child (Viewer) window = " + AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1]);
browser.switchTo().window(window2);
scenario.write(browser.getCurrentUrl());
scenario.write(browser.getTitle());
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("content")));
Screenshot.takeScreenshot(BaseSteps.scenario, browser);
WebElement pdfViewer = browser.findElement(By.id("content"));
assertThat(pdfViewer.isDisplayed())
    .overridingErrorMessage("The pdf viewer window is launched, but there is no content is displayed.")
    .isTrue();

browser.switchTo().window(window2).close();
```

here is the error... (error pops at "wait.until" line....

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.id: content (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at Utilities.Common.viewTheContentsWithPDFViewer(Common.java:268)
    at Steps.Steps.Verify_the_pdfviewer_is_launching_with_data_content_for_that_item(Steps.java:157)
    at ✽.And Verify the pdfviewer is launching with data content for that item(Returns.feature:19)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#content"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.87)
```

Comment: the order of windows in the array returned by getWindowHandles() is not reliable.  Use GetCurrentWindowHandle to get the current handle before clicking the link that opens a new window.  Aftwards, check your array for the value that is not that handle... this will be the new window's handle.  Btw, you may also want to sleep a bit before taking the screenshot.  The div could be there well before the PDF is loaded.  Unfortunately the DOM won't know much about that embedded content.

Comment: i tried with defaultwindowhandle, but still it does not identify the second window elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue. In my case the attribute of the element was changing and I used contains in xpath.

Try checking whether there is a frame and also use fluent wait